# Is it possible to build a linear bound automata that decides A(NFA)?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability

Is it possible to build a linear bound automata that decides A(NFA)?

A(NFA)=Accepting Non deterministic Automata - language that contains the encoding of all the NFAs together with the strings that the NFA accepts

I tried to look online, in summaries and handouts and even in several books (including Sipser's book), but couldn't find any indication on it.

I tried converting NFA to DFA and then build an NFA with the LBA with a tape the size of the tree but not sure if that's the right solution and how to calculate the length of the tape.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: What is "A(NFA)"? Can you please be explicit about the language description?

Comment: Hi Nir, 
Accepting Non deterministic Automata - language that contains the encoding of all the NFAs together with the strings that the NFA accepts.
I'll update the title.